# Передать classLoader в Worker

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Необходимо подгрзить .dex модуль внутри Worker'а, выполнение которого запланировано с помощью WorkManager'а. Поскольку использовать classLoader из этого Worker'а нельзя, стоит задача его каким-то образом передать. Я пробовал сериализовать classLoader с помощью Gson (хотел передать с помощью setInputData), но переполняется стек.